# Simple JavaScript code does not work with nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, fs

I am an experienced JavaScript programmer, but am just starting to learn [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

Using node, I want to read the contents of a directory, and print out files of only a specific extension. Both the directory and file-extension will be given by command-line arguments.

But, I also want to push myself and explore JavaScript programming concepts as I solve these puzzles, so I wanted to create a `File` object to store information about a file, and use that to solve the problem.

Becaause of this, my approach *is* overly-complex, and I know that there are simpler ways of doing this, but I just want an answer which solves my current problem:

### Why does node.js throw the following error

```
this.baseName = /.+(?=\.[^.]+)/.exec(file)[0];
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

### in this code:

```js
function File(file){
  if (file instanceof File) return file;
  if (!(this instanceof File)) return new File(file);

  if (typeof file !== "string") throw new Error("Useful error." + typeof(file));

  this.fullName = file;

  /*vvvvvvvvvvvv  Important Bit  vvvvvvvvvvvvvv*/
  this.baseName = /.+(?=\.[^.]+)/.exec(file)[0];
  this.extension = /[^.]+(?=$)/.exec(file)[0];
}

File.prototype = {
  isOfType: function(ext){
    return ext === this.extension;
  }
}

var fs = require('fs');
var argv = process.argv;

fs.readdir(argv[2], function(err, list){
  var res = list.filter(function(element, index, array){
    var file = new File(element);
    return file.isOfType(argv[3]);
  });
  console.log(res);
});
```

but, in a Chrome js console, it runs fine (with simulated `process` and `fs` objects of course).

To me (inexperienced me) it looks like node could be making several mistakes:

1. Not handling the regex properly (I've done tests and this seems likely)
2. Using square brackets to find key `'0'` within object, instead of index `0` within array.

Or I could be making several mistakes:

1. Not understanding `fs.readdir` and its necessary callback.
2. Not understanding possible differences between constructors in JavaScript and Node

Please help, I'd like an answer that solves or explains my current problem, not one that works around it.

Thanks.

Comment: find out: before your offending line, try a `console.log(file, /.+(?=\.[^.]+)/.exec(file))` and see what it says (for understanding your code, it'd also be better to rename that from `file` to `fileName`). Also, fairly confused about your use of `if (!(this instanceof File))`, that is not a test you should ever need to make.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried your test, and I think I get it now: `fs.readdir` also places directory names in the returned list (possibly?), which don't have a dot or extension, so no match is found. Could this be the case?

Comment: Is there a .DS_Store file in the directory you are testing? The regex will not match anything on that, so you will get a null (and it will throw that error).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In fact, that looks very plausible, here's the output of your test just before an error is thrown: `BefunExec-master null` exec returns nothing.

Comment: Also - use the path module for picking apart file names. Don't use ad hoc regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node has a [built in](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) way to check for valid files

```
function File(file){
  if (file instanceof File) return file;
  if (!(this instanceof File)) return new File(file);

  if (typeof file !== "string") throw new Error("Useful error." + typeof(file));

  var stat = fs.statSync(file);

  if ( stat && stat.isFile() ) {

      this.fullName = file;

      /*vvvvvvvvvvvv  Important Bit  vvvvvvvvvvvvvv*/
      this.baseName = /.+(?=\.[^.]+)/.exec(file)[0];
      this.extension = /[^.]+(?=$)/.exec(file)[0];
  }
}
```

Node also has a [built in](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) way to get extensions and path names

```
var path = require('path');

var basename = path.basename(file);

var extension = path.extname(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does node.js throw the following error
>
> `this.baseName = /.+(?=\.[^.]+)/.exec(file)[0];`
>                                             ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Because `file` doesn't match the regular expression, and so `exec` returns `null`; then you're doing `null[0]`, which throws the exception. That would happen for a name like `a` or `a.`, for instance, or the `.` and `..` pseudo-directories.

Use the NodeJS debugger or just `console.log` file` immediately prior, an you'll see the value that's causing trouble.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realise directories were also included in the list passed by `readdir`. It seems that that was causing the problem. Any way to quickly and neatly solve this?

Comment: @minseong: If you consider the base name to be anything prior to the first `.`, and the extension to be the `.` and anything after it, perhaps `var result = /(.+?)(\.?.+)?/.exec(file);` and then `this.baseName = result[0];` and `this.extension = result[1];` You'd only get `null` for a blank string then, but note that `..` would give you `.` as the name and `.` as the extension. Or just use `indexOf` and `substring`.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. As in, the error went, but it's not matching files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because any file names which don't match your regular expression, such as many directory names (which are included in your `list` variable), will then return null here:

```
/.+(?=\.[^.]+)/.exec(file)
```

so you are trying to do

```
null[0]
```

which will not work.

I solved this by simply checking for a period within the file name:

```
var file = (element.indexOf(".") > -1) ? new File(element) : false;
return (file) ? file.isOfType(argv[3]) : false;
```

within the filter, so final code resembles:

```
fs.readdir(argv[2], function(err, list){
  var res = list.filter(function(element, index, array){
    var file = (element.indexOf(".") > -1) ? new File(element) : false;
    return (file) ? file.isOfType(argv[3]) : false;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; console.log(res[i++]));
});
```